# Logical grouping of arbitrary number of plots in R

Tags: r, plot, par

I have `n` plots that I want to display in a grid in a single image in R. Using `par` I can specify beforehand the number of rows and columns to divide the plot. For example, for `n = 4`, it makes most sense to organize 4 plots in a square 2x2 grid.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(p1)
plot(p2)
plot(p3)
plot(p4)
```

I'd like this to work for arbitrary `n`, however. So, for example, let's say I want to plot 12 plots side by side. It's most practical that the resulting grid of plots be as square-like as possible: so, I'd like a 3x4 grid `par(mfrow=c(3, 4))`, rather than a 12x1 `par(mfrow=c(12, 1))`. Or, if I want to plot 11 plots, leaving the 12th grid empty would be fine.

Is there a quick way to do this in R? Otherwise I suppose I have to do some algebra - this is an optimization problem, minimizing the perimeter of the grid given a fixed area `n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grDevices::n2mfrow()` can do it for you

Answer (score 0):

For `nplots` plots, how about:

`rows = floor(sqrt(nplots))
columns = ceiling(sqrt(nplots))
par(mfrow=c(rows,columns))`